# Bash: how to name a file after numeric id of previous file in same folder?

Tags: bash, filenames, sequence

I am trying to create a simple script for taking notes from the command line. The file names should contain each note's number and creation date. Like so:

```
01_20130711.txt
02_20130722.txt
03_20130731.txt
...
```

Thus, the note numbers should simply count upwards from the last note I entered. Also, when the notes folder is empty, the first file created there should get `01` as its number.

How can I accomplish an automatic numeration of this kind?

Comment: I read [this](http://www.unix.com/302440347-post3.html) and experimented with `echo ${name}$((num+1))`, but had issues with `BASH_REMATCH`. Fair criticism, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set *.txt
[[ ${*: -1} =~ [0-9]+ ]]
printf -v next '%02d_%d.txt' $(( BASH_REMATCH + 1 )) $(date +%Y%m%d)
touch $next
```

Comment: Thank you! This explains some issues I had with `BASH_REMATCH`. Additional note for n00bs like me: add `cat > $next` as last line, and you'll have a working "application".

Comment: Note that BASH_REMATCH is actually an array. Referencing it without the index is equivalent to `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`, i.e. the first element only, which in this case is what you need. Subsequent elements of the array will hold the contents of capturing parentheses, ex: `[[ 'abc' =~ (.)(.)(.) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}` outputs "c"

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, good explanation; this is one of the issues I had, and I linked another example in my comment for the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lastfile = `ls -lrth | tail -n 1`
lastnumber = `echo $lastfile | awk -F"_" '{print $1}'`
```

To get the number of last node. I think the rest of script is clear now.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting alternative, but I prefer Steven Penny's solution since it explained an issue I had myself. Also @StevenPenny thanks for the link, very useful!